# tom todger meaning

Tags: etymology

I have been researching the meaning of "tom todger" as used by New Zealand/Australian author Ruth Park in her autobiography A Fence Around the Cuckoo (Penguin Books 1993 pb Page 90). Her Irish grandmother, born mid-19th Century, called Park a "tom todger" in the 1930s.

Answer (score 2):

*Todger* is British slang for penis, but it only dates from around 1987. It's a variant of *tadger*, from around 1947. So I don't think Ruth Park meant this.

Here's an extract from Ruth Park's novel *The Harp in the South* (serialised in the [*Sydney Morning Herald*](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/27903865) in 1947):

> She trotted rapidly out to the kitchen, holding an agitated conversation with herself as she went. And
>   Grandma's nose had not lied. There
>   was Hughie, his black brows bent
>   downwards into a solid line, concentrating on a series of sticky brown
>   paper bags before him, the contents of which he was'measuring out into
>   the washing-up basin.
>
> "Ah, yer tom todger," commenced
>   Grandma mildly, in a tone which
>   brought to mind the precise and gentle
>   pacings of a bull before he starts
>   tearing up the earth.

From the context, it sounds more like a nonsense name, similar to saying "Ah, yer daft apoth" or "Ah, yer silly sausage".

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with _[The Life and Adventures of Martin Chuzzlewit](http://www.wordnik.com/words/Todgers)_ by Dickens. Todgers is a boarding house in that novel, and all its denizens are definitely weird.

Comment: It's worth adding that "apoth" (or *ha'p'orth*) is how *half-penny-worth* is pronounced. It's definitely idiomatic, because using it as a term of endearment to describe a **person** isn't even in OED.

Comment: @Andrew: The OED says the entry has not yet been fully updated and the latest citation is 1891 so I expect it to be added in due course.